Does there exist an associative, commutative, and bijective (up to reordering) binary operation on the natural numbers?
Here's where the motivation comes from. I was trying to figure out a way to assign a unique natural number to every pure set (that is, I wanted to find a bijective function with a domain of pure sets and a codomain of $\mathbb{N}$). I was trying to do this recursively: that is, a set's "set number" (as I will call it for now) should be some function of its elements' set numbers. At first, I tried to use multiplication; that is, a set's set number is the product of its elements' set numbers -- but, among other problems, this is not unique; the set containing elements with set numbers $2$ and $9$ would have the same set number as the set containing elements with set numbers $3$ and $6$.
Thus came about my question:

Does there exist an associative, commutative, and bijective (up to reordering) binary operation on the natural numbers?

The three conditions all arise from the problem: associativity and commutativity are both necessary because sets are unordered, and we should get the same result no matter what order we choose to input the elements' set numbers into the function. Bijectivity (up to reordering) implies that for each output, we can deduce the input -- this seems tricky since we're trying to go from $\mathbb{N}^2$ to $\mathbb{N}$, but this is possible (for example, superimposing the naturals in diagonal lines over a grid of ordered pairs of naturals, as Cantor did when proving that the rationals and the naturals have the same cardinality). The question is, is there a way to get all three criteria?
In addition, the simpler the operation is, the better; though it's not necessary for the purposes of this problem, it would be nice if it were something you can understand intuitively.
Does such a thing exist? Thanks for your time!

"bijectivity" is unclear.  Since $a\ast b= b\ast a$, it can't be bijective.  Do you mean to say that it is bijective up to re-ordering?  Something else?

Oh, I didn't think about that -- yes, I'm looking for bijectivity up to re-ordering. (Editied accordingly.)

I suggest thinking it through.  Bijectivity is extremely strong...very hard to imagine that anything is possible.  Try writing down basic consequences of that.

I see where this is going... if you say $0 * 0 = k$ and $0 * 1 = n$, we know that $(0 * 0) * 1 = 0 * (0 * 1)$ and so $k * 1 = 0 * n$... does that prove it impossible?

Well, I wouldn't call $0$ a natural number, but right.  I've written out a short argument below.

@Pranay clever thought, but I don't think it works.  My argument still holds...$a\ast b = 1\implies (a,b)=(1,1)$.  If that is out of the domain, then $1$ is out of the image.

By pure set, do you mean finite set? You might want to just invent an ordering of the finite subsets of $\Bbb N$, since there are countably infinitely many of them.

Would this work for your needs? Let SetRank(∅) = 1 ( For x with positive cardinality n,  SetRank(x) = 2^SetRank(x_1) * ... * 2^SetRank(x_n) where x_1,...x_n are the elements of x?

I'm looking for something that you can figure a set's elements from the number, and you wouldn't be able to do that with your suggestion.

Although it can't be done, the square-free natural numbers form a Boolean group.  Also, I still don't know what you mean by bijective in this context.

This operation can not exist.  To see that:
Step $1$:  for any $a\in \mathbb N$, $a\ast a = a$.
Proof:  Fix $n\in \mathbb N$.  Then we must have some pair $a,b$ with $a\ast b = n$.  But then, for any natural number $c$ we have $a\ast (b\ast c)= n\ast c$ which implies that $a=n$.  Similarly $b=n$ and we are done.
Step $2$:  contradiction
Take any pair of natural numbers $(a,b)$.  Then $$a\ast b =(a\ast a)\ast b=a\ast (b\ast a)$$
It follows that $b = b\ast a$ for all $b\in \mathbb N$, which is not possible.
Simpler contradiction:  If $a\neq b$ then what could $a\ast b$ be?  If $a\ast b = n=n\ast n$ then we again contradict bijectivity.

Why does $a*(bc) = nc$ for all $c$ imply that $a=n$?

@Pranay  Well...bijectivity would tell us that, for any fixed $c$, we must have at least one of $a=n$ or $a=c$.  But we can't have $a=c$ for more than one value of $c$.

Oh right! Thanks for explaining!
